Changing bash doesn't work
I'm using Starship, but don't get the proper changes, and I have to run the command bash just to see the starship terminal. I want this to happen by default.
I also have Tmux, when I load that, it gives me the starship bash, but if I try loading it on default, I get the Ubuntu bash, like.
fizcakez@IWANTHUGS:~$
instead of the starship terminal.
Also, when I change to the starship bash, it says I'm using /bin/bash, and the same happens when I'm using the Ubuntu bash.
Please help me, how do I change it to where I only get the starship terminal?

Which version of Ubuntu are you using? How did you install Starship? Have you changed the file ~/.bashrc? Edit your question and add these information.

latest, brew install, yes.

also, starship works, I have to manually load it for it to appear tho

Are you, or the install scripts using chsh? That will only accept shells listed in /etc/shells.

Are you using Ubuntu or MacOS? Which version?

I cant even see shells in /etc
I'm using Ubuntu, why else am I here?
